# How to classify tree cover overlapping roofs in eCognition

Tags: land-classification, image-classification, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, ecognition

This might be a fairly simple question, but I'm new to eCognition. I'm using Developer 10.2. For canopy that overlaps rooftops, I need to define these areas as separate objects and classify as canopy.

I am using NAIP 4-band imagery and a lidar-derived height band. I developed a ruleset for classifying an invasive species. First, I created a **Vegetation** class based on NDVI *automatic threshold*, then from that class, created a  **Canopy** subclass based on the lidar height band (height > 2 m). However, there are some buildings with high NDVI values that are misclassified as Canopy. The yellow outline in the image below is a Structures vector layer, some parts of which are misclassified as Canopy.
[image: Structures outlined in yellow, misclassified as Canopy]

From the Structures vector file, I originally created a **Structures** class using *vector-based segmentation* (class filter: Canopy) and *assign class by thematic layer*. This was fine where no canopy overlapped the roof:
[image: Classification of structures based on vector file/thematic layer]

...but had the effect of clipping off the overlying canopy and classifying that as Structure:
[image: Canopy misclassified as Structure]

[image: Canopy misclassified as Structure]

Overlapping tree canopy is discussed by Jarlath O'Neil-Dunne in the eCognition Webinar "[Data Fusion Approaches to Tree Canopy Change Detection](https://youtu.be/sHeb1_43F3c?t=1490)" (at 24:50).
[image: Screenshot of webinar; magenta is the canopy overlapping the rooftops]

He says he "used the buildings on the sublevel" to find the overlapping tree canopy. Then the *relative border to* algorithm was used to reclassify those overlapping objects. This is what I need to accomplish, but I'm having trouble navigating the levels. Because I segmented my Canopy class to create the Structures class, these objects don't overlap. How do I define those overlapping instances as Canopy using the Structures class on a sublevel?

Answer (score 1):

I did find a workaround:

Nearly all roofs misclassified as canopy are blue, with values of B > ~120. I removed the step of classifying buildings based on the vector layer entirely, then added an algorithm to pull out misclassified roofs from the segmented canopy by classifying Blue > 120 as "potential structure". It's not perfect, but it is better.

Before:
[image: Before]

After (B>120):[image: After (B>120)]